# Debugging Javascript and diving into Nodejs c++ code

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio, node.js, debugging

I am very new to web development and I have started development using node.js.

For my application i need to debug code both of my javascript and nodejs c++ implementation code. I tried Visual Studio 2010. It worked good for c++ debugging part but i failed to breakpoint on javascript code. I then searched the forums and found [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector). It worked beautifully on javascript part but could not dive into c++ code. All this took me one long day.

Is there a way or a debugger that i can use ?